# How to access data inside <SOAP-ENV:Header> via PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to use PHP's `SoapClient` class to query a web service. It works fine, to a degree, but I want to access something that I'm getting back in the `<SOAP-ENV:Header>` section of the response - and am struggling to see how!

If I make the following call:

```
$transactions = $soapClient->getTransactionList($params);
$response = $soapClient->__getLastResponse();
```

The contents of `$response` is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://api.affiliatewindow.com/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns1:getQuotaResponse>123456</ns1:getQuotaResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:getTransactionListResponse>
            <ns1:getTransactionListReturn>
                <ns1:Transaction>
                    <-- Data here, removed for brevity -->
                </ns1:Transaction>
                <ns1:Transaction>
                    <-- Data here, removed for brevity -->
                </ns1:Transaction>
                <ns1:Transaction>
                    <-- Data here, removed for brevity -->
                </ns1:Transaction>
            </ns1:getTransactionListReturn>
        </ns1:getTransactionListResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My `$transactions` variable includes an array of transactions that correspond to the contents of `<SOAP-ENV:Body>`, which is great, but how do I access the value of `getQuotaResponse`, which sits inside `<SOAP-ENV:Header>`?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a nicer way accessing data in the header, but you could use,

```
preg_match("/getQuotaResponse>([^<]+)/",$response, $match); 
echo $match[1];
```

Output:

```
123456
```

Comment: Yeah, although you could do that I'm really trying to avoid it. I figured there must be a way of accessing this through `SoapClient`…

Comment: You could try using [__soapCall()](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php). `$soapClient->__soapCall("getTransactionList", $params, null, $input_headers, $output_headers);` and check what `$output_headers` contains.

Comment: That sounded like it may work! However, I'm getting the following error: `Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Error cannot find parameter` - can't figure out what's causing that either…

Comment: Try removing `$input_headers`, or setting it to an empty array, might be what is causing it.

Comment: Yeah, tried that, and passing `null` (which is the default) with no luck unfortunately!

Comment: If you can share your code where you connect to the server and what your `$params` looks like I am sure the problem can be solved. If it contains confidential information you can use the regex as a temporary solution.